# Java Swing Library to support DIgital like Character Displays

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am building a Java Swing based video game, and I would like to have the scores and related data dispayed in a digital like format or the electro-mechanical displays you used to see on pinball machines.

Does anyone know of a free Java Swing Library that can support this?

Thanks

Comment: Would be pretty easy to make yourself, just extend JComponent, pass in how many digits, the color, the number to display, add a setScore method, and define 10 different methods to draw each different digit as you loop over the score instance variable's digits in paintComponent.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a  "digital font" out there that you could download and use.

Comment: Are you talking about a [seven segment number display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display)?